# Assign null string to gets

Tags: c, string, null, eof

I want to write a program in C that fills an array p[MAX][N] of strings

I used this but i dont know which is the null string to enter when i give input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define R 3
#define C 8

int main()
{
    int i;
    char strings[R][C]; 
    printf("***Table of Strings - Names***\n\n");
    for(i=0;(i<R && gets(strings[i]));i++)
    ;           
    if(i==R)
    printf("\n**Table Full - input terminated \n");
    for(i=0;i<R;i++)
        puts(strings[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, never use `gets()`.  It is inherently dangerous as it doesn't do any bounds checking on the memory you pass to it.  Use `fgets()` instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < R && fgets(strings[i], C, stdin); ++i);
```

Note that `fgets()` will leave any new line ('\n') in the input at the end of the string, assuming that the whole line can fit in your buffer.  If the whole line can't fit in your buffer, then it reads as much as can fit into your buffer (leaving room for and always appending a nul terminator), stops reading the input at that point and leaves the rest of the input on the stream.  With `C` being so small in your program, such an occurrence is quite likely.

Alternatively, you could use `getline()` if it's available on your platform:

```
char *strings[R] = { 0 };
size_t cap;

for (i = 0; i < R && 0 <= getline(&strings[i], (cap = 0, &cap), stdin));

if (i == R)
  printf("\n**Table Full - input terminated \n");

for (i = 0; i < R && strings[i]; ++i)
    puts(strings[i]);

/* program done; clean up strings */

for (i = 0; i < R && strings[R]; ++i)
  free(strings[R]);
```

`getline()` automatically dynamically (re)allocates the memory necessary to fit the next line from the input stream.  It also leaves any new line ('\n') in the input at the end of the string.

Second, ctrl-D is typically used terminate the input to a program from a terminal.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, SO THE NULL STRING IS CTRL-D? I want to use it to classroom and i dont want to use pointer to string . i will try fgets now and i will tell

Comment: @XanthoulaAtsalaki No, ctrl-D isn't "the null string."  Ctrl-D signals the end of input to the process.  So, after you use ctrl-D, then you can't send it any more input through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. I changed it to this

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,max,thesi,sum=0,countCH=0,mikos=0;
    char strings[R][C]; 

    printf("***Table of Strings - Names***\n\n");
for(i=0;(i<R && fgets(strings[i],C,stdin ));i++)
    ;

if(i==R)
    printf("\n**Table Full - input terminated \n");
for(i=0;i<R;i++)
    fputs(strings[i],stdout);
//Euresh megistou string
max=0;
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<R;i++)
{


        mikos=strlen(strings[i])-1;
        sum+=mikos; 
        if(mikos>max)
        {

            max=mikos;
            thesi=i;
        }
}

printf("\nTo string me to megalitero mikos einai auto pou brisketai sthn %d seira \nkai einai to %s \nme mhkos %d",thesi+1,strings[thesi],max);
printf("\nO pinakas me ta strings periexei %d xaraktires\n",sum);


return 0;   

}
It works just fine only that strlen counts all the chars of the string including null char why is that i dont get it?
```

Comment: Like I said in my answer, `fgets` will leave the new line character ('\n') at the end of the string, so long as there is room for it.  That is why the `strlen` is one more than you expect, not because of the nul terminator ('\0').